# Chinese Remainder theorem on the ring of integers modulo n

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Consider the Chinese remainder theorem for 2 integers ie mapping one congruence to 2 . I want to show this is a ring homomorphism. While this is doable by showing every individual property of ring homomorphisms, I was wondering if theres a way to do this more simply.

Comment: "every individual property"? Aren't there only two properties: additivity and multiplicativity?

Comment: 3 actually . Identity preservation too, thats fairly trivial in this case though.

Comment: @Muzzi: Those are called “unital ring homomorphisms”. If you want morphisms to map the multiplicative unity to the multiplicative unity, you need to say so.

Comment: The Chinese Remainder Theorem is, at its heart, a statement that under suitable conditions there is an isomorphism between $R/(I_1\cap\cdots\cap I_n)$ and $(R/I_1)\times(R/I_2)\times\cdots\times(R/I_n)$, induced by the natural map $R\to (R/I_1)\times\cdots\times (R/I_n)$. In fact, it’s possible to just state it that way. Is that what you want?

Comment: Not exactly,  I want to show that this map is a homomorphism without directly verifying these properties

Comment: @Muzzi: The fact that you have a homomorphism $R\to (R/I_1)\times\cdots\times (R/I_n)$ follows form the categorical properties of the products, and the fact that the maps $R\to R/I_j$ are already known to be homomorphisms. This gives you, by the Fundamental Theorem of Homomorphisms, that the map $R/(I_1\cap\cdots\cap I_n)\to (R/I_1)\times\cdots\times (R/I_n)$ is necessarily a homomorphism. You don’t need to “direclty verif[y additivity and multiplicativity]”. The CRT tells you the map is surjective.

Comment: @Muzzi: So how is it “not exactly”?

Comment: Okay, I didn't get it in the previous comment. Sorry for the confusion. Your explanation is great thanks.